# Custom Scalar Types in Eigen: Ambiguous overload for operator*

Tags: eigen

I am trying to integrate FloatX (https://github.com/oprecomp/FloatX) into Eigen but am getting an error anytime I do any matrix multiplication:

```
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator*'
```

I have the following according to the documentation for adding custom scalar types in Eigen:

```
namespace Eigen {
    template<int E, int M>
    struct NumTraits<flx::floatx<E,M>> : NumTraits<double>
    {
        typedef flx::floatx<E,M> Real;
        typedef flx::floatx<E,M> NonInteger;
        typedef flx::floatx<E,M> Nested;

        enum {
            IsComplex = 0,
            IsInteger = 0,
            IsSigned = 1,
            RequireInitialization = 0,
            ReadCost = 1,
            AddCost = 3,
            MulCost = 3
        };
    };

    template<typename BinaryOp, typename A, int E, int M>
    struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<A,flx::floatx<E,M>,BinaryOp> { typedef flx::floatx<E,M> ReturnType; };

    template<typename BinaryOp, typename A, int E, int M>
    struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<flx::floatx<E,M>,A,BinaryOp> { typedef flx::floatx<E,M> ReturnType; };

    template<typename BinaryOp, int E, int M>
    struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<flx::floatx<E,M>,flx::floatx<E,M>,BinaryOp> { typedef flx::floatx<E,M> ReturnType; };
 
        template <int E, int M>
        struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<
        flx::floatx<E,M>, flx::floatx<E,M>,
        internal::scalar_product_op<flx::floatx<E,M>,
        flx::floatx<E,M>>> {
            typedef flx::floatx<E,M> ReturnType;
        };      
}
```

The inclusion of the `ScalarBinaryOpTraits` at the bottom does not help or hurt, seemingly. I get the same error regardless if I include them. Any help is appreciated!

#### Edit

Here's a simple example that reproduces the error (need to download `floatx.hpp` from https://github.com/oprecomp/FloatX/blob/master/src/floatx.hpp):

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

#include "floatx.hpp"

using fx = flx::floatx<8,23>;

// support for eigen library
namespace Eigen {
    template<int E, int M>
    struct NumTraits<flx::floatx<E,M>> : NumTraits<double>
    {
        typedef flx::floatx<E,M> Real;
        typedef flx::floatx<E,M> NonInteger;
        typedef flx::floatx<E,M> Nested;
      
        enum {
            IsComplex = 0,
            IsInteger = 0,
            IsSigned = 1,
            RequireInitialization = 0,
            ReadCost = 1,
            AddCost = 3,
            MulCost = 3
        };
    };
}

int main() {
    Eigen::Matrix<fx,3,3> m;
    m << fx(1), fx(2), fx(3),
         fx(4), fx(5), fx(6),
         fx(7), fx(8), fx(9);

    Eigen::Matrix<fx,3,3> m2 = m * m;

    std::cout << m;
    std::cout << m2;
}
```

Output:

```
g++ -I /usr/include/eigen3 floatx.hpp test.cpp -o floatx_test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:35:34: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘Eigen::Matrix<flx::floatx<8, 23>, 3, 3>’ and ‘Eigen::Matrix<flx::floatx<8, 23>, 3, 3>’)
```

Comment: I assume `floatx` has some kind of `template<class T> floatx operator(floatx, T);` overload which conflicts with Eigen's `Scalar * Matrix` overloads. Try to provide a [mre] (ideally factor out the relevant parts of FloatX.

Comment: I've added an example. I think you're right, I think there's some conflict with the templating/overloading present in both floatx and Eigen.

Comment: Looks like the problem is the constructor `template <typename T> FLOATX_ATTRIBUTES floatxr(const T& other)`. Are you able to make this explicit?

Comment: By making that constructor explicit, the program compiles and runs. Thanks for the help!